# Is this well known?

Tags: continued-fractions, golden-ratio

How to prove $$1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{e^{-2\pi}}{1+\cfrac{e^{-4\pi}}{1+\cfrac{e^{-6\pi}}{\cdots}}}} = \left(\sqrt{5\phi}-\phi\right) e^{2\pi/5}.$$ i dont know how to do it. like if there were repeating terms we put it to be $z$ and then again $1/z$ and solve the quadratic  but how to go for this. Note that I am interested if there is a  way using elementary knowledge as I am only in grade $12$. Thanks!

Comment: How did you come across this?

Comment: Ramanujan's papers...

Comment: while surfing on the net

Comment: can you give some link @Olivier Oloa

Comment: I certainly looks like Ramanujan. $\qquad$

Comment: This one:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_continued_fraction or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujanContinuedFractions.html or https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0015